# React Native State cannot be passed to signature screen pen color

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
state = { pencolor: "pink"}

    <SignatureScreen
            penColor = {this.state.pencolor}
            onOK = {this.handleSignature}
            onEmpty={this.handleEmpty}
  
            backgroundColor="rgb(0,0,0)"
            size={{width: 20, height: 70}}
            autoClear={true}
            />

_randompencolor(){ // working 
    var pencolors = ['white', 'pink', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'orange']
    console.log(pencolors);
    var randomcolor = pencolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*pencolors.length)];
    this.setState({pencolor: randomcolor})
    console.log(this.state.pencolor);
    console.log("This is the random color selected");
    console.log(randomcolor)

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH7FC.png
```

- function calling is called at the top and the setting of state works
- the penColor works when its penColor = 'white' but does not work when this.state.pencolor is placed.
- the var randomcolor is a randomizer which randomizes and select one color from the array.
- I'm trying to make it such that every time my user writes and confirms on the signature pad, the next signature color would be different as my application is for kids.

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question, also code snippet doesn't help to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax wise i don't see any problem with your code. One thing doesn't look correct

```js
var randomcolor = pencolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*pencolors.length)];
```

Maths.floor will round off the number to integer. But i cannot guaranty the value between 0 and 5, which is the range of your pencolors  array.

I would suggest replace with below line and try.

```js
var randomcolor = pencolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)%pencolors.length];
```

Comment: the randomizer does not seem to have any problem as it is able to display a different color when I console log the var randomcolor. Through the console logging of the state.pencolor, I am able to confirm that the color in the state changes correctly. As shown in the image link above. This is what makes me baffled as there does not seem to be a problem with my code but the changing of pencolor using the this.state.pencolor just does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add more code details for the < SignatureScreen/ > component.

Or you can add a log in `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

```js
// < SignatureScreen/ >
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //...
    console.log(nextProps.penColor, this.props.penColor)
}
```

Comment: This is all the details i have for the signature screen, the other codes for the signature screen is just the handlesignature which captures the signature pad and saves it into the phone

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help regarding this question. It is now able to work after i change the state from state = {pencolor: 'pink'} to this.state = {pencolor: 'pink'};